Understanding MOTChallenge dataset format
I was looking into MOT17 datasets. And I have some stupid questions regarding dataset:
Q1. Why there is no ground truth files in test datasets? For example MOT17/test/MOT17-01-DPM has folders det, img1 and a file seqinfo.ini while MOT17/train/MOT17-02-DPM also has folder gt along with the three in case of test folder.
Q2. Am trying to understand the content of txt files. For 2D datasets, I guess the CSV format is:  frame_id, object_id, bb_left, bb_top, bb_width, bb_height, conf, -1, -1, -1, where bb stands for bounding box and conf stands for confidence score. Now in ground truth file gt.txt, each frame occurs only once:
1,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1
2,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1
3,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1
4,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1
5,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1
6,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1
7,1,912,484,97,109,0,7,1

As you can see above, there is no repetition for frame number across different lines.
Q3. Does this mean that in ground truths only one object is detected per frame?
Q4. If answer to Q3 is yes, that is if ground truth does indeed contain one object per frame, then why is this so? Especially when there are repetitions of frame numbers across different lines in detection file det.txt indicating muliplt detected objects / bounding boxes per frame:
1,-1,1359.1,413.27,120.26,362.77,2.3092,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,571.03,402.13,104.56,315.68,1.5028,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,650.8,455.86,63.98,193.94,0.33276,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,721.23,446.86,41.871,127.61,0.27401,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,454.06,434.36,97.492,294.47,0.20818,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,1254.6,446.72,33.822,103.47,0.14776,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,1301.1,237.38,195.98,589.95,0.051818,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,1480.3,413.27,120.26,362.77,-0.020474,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,552.72,473.9,29.314,89.943,-0.087553,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,1097,433,39,119,-0.17964,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,543.19,442.1,44.948,136.84,-0.3683,-1,-1,-1
1,-1,1017,425,39,119,-0.41789,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,1359.1,413.27,120.26,362.77,2.4731,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,584.04,446.86,84.742,256.23,1.2369,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,729,457,39,119,0.40858,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,460.48,442.1,90.896,274.69,0.26749,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,643.66,461.78,59.629,180.89,0.18023,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,1494.4,408.29,112.14,338.41,0.16075,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,572.83,364.89,128.96,388.88,-0.011851,-1,-1,-1
2,-1,1097,433,39,119,-0.185,-1,-1,-1

